# Captured image overwrites previous picture when i take picture after closing and reopening the app

Tags: android-tabhost, android-xml

I have posted java code and the snapshot of the activity. The camera tab has a button and imagepreview widget. The camera is functioning properly. How to save the picture in a particular folder called pictures. And I'm not getting preview of the image.

Here's my java code:

```
public class activities extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1777;
ImageView imgPreview;
Button btnCapturePicture;
File file;
static int count=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activities);

    TabHost th=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    th.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.camera);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.chat);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat15));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.profile);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag4");
    specs.setContent(R.id.history);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.history2));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs=th.newTabSpec("Tag5");
    specs.setContent(R.id.settings);
    specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings5));
    th.addTab(specs);

    imgPreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview6);
    btnCapturePicture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);

    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "IMG_"+count+++".jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //Check that request code matches ours:
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "IMG_"+count+++".jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight)
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
    {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
}
```

Here's my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>-->
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageview6" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Take a Picture"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/textView18" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Grade"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:id="@+id/textView19" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Credit Balance"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView20" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Invite Friends"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:src="@drawable/invite"
                        android:layout_marginStart="213dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:foregroundGravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view4"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Change Password"
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:src="@drawable/change_passg"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="170dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view5"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>




            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/history"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:id="@+id/view6"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="#bdbdbd">
                    </View>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Add Credits"
                        android:id="@+id/textView21" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view7"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Report Issue"
                        android:id="@+id/textView22" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view8"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rate Us"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView23" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view9"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="FAQ"
                        android:id="@+id/textView24" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view10"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Feedback"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView25" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view11"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd">
                </View>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Logout"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/button6" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In my old day of API18 I use a SurfaceView to hold the preview and android.hardware.camera (now you should use android.hardware.camera2) to access the camera. In the old Camera object I can setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder()) to make the preview shown on the surface. I didn't work on that anymore after API21 so you need to have some research yourself.

Comment: I am getting preview first time. Next time when I capture photo not able to see the preview. And when i close and open the app the latest picture overwrites the previous one. I think there is a name conflict. How to solve this problem? any idea?

Comment: When you take a photo, call the camera object's stopPreview(), and then the takePicture() method and process the jpegCallback > create a FileOutputStream, and write the photo to the memory. You have to generate a new file name for each photo you have, and you may also want to use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() to let Android index your photo and make it appear in the Photos app. After all these actions, do leave a few seconds before you call the camera object's startPreview() again (eg using a handler and postDelay).